# Textbox fill logic

Tags: jquery

I have two fields (#PageHeadingTxt and #MetaTitleTxt). Initially both are blank. Whenever a user enters any data in the #PageHeadingTxt textbox, the same data should fill the other textbox as well. I had no problems getting there but and additional requirement is that when the user manually changes the #MetaTitleTxt input then the content from #PageHeadingTxt should no longer be mirrored into #MetaTitleTxt. Here's my code:

```
var metaTitleHasBeenEdited = 0;
$('#MetaTitleTxt').on('focus',function(){
$(this).on('keyup',function(){
    metaTitleHasBeenEdited ++;
    });
});
$('#PageHeadingTxt').on('focus',function(){
if (metaTitleHasBeenEdited <=0 ) {
    $('#PageHeadingTxt').on('input',function(){
        $('#MetaTitleTxt').val($('#PageHeadingTxt').val());
        });
    }
});
```

Now the content from the first textbox gets mirrored into the second one no matter what. Any help appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have error in jquery: ' single quotes is missing following is example

```
$('#MetaTitleTxt').val($('#MetaTitleTxt).val());
                                       ^
```

Don't know why you are picking text of **MetaTitleTxt** and putting at same text box

### Updated Code

```
$(function(){
    var metaTitleHasBeenEdited = 0;
    $('#MetaTitleTxt').on('focus',function(){
        $(this).on('keyup',function(){
            metaTitleHasBeenEdited ++;
        });
    });
    $('#PageHeadingTxt').on('focus',function(){
        $('#PageHeadingTxt').on('keyup',function(){
                if (metaTitleHasBeenEdited <=0 ) {
                $('#MetaTitleTxt').val($('#PageHeadingTxt').val());
                }
            });

    });
});
```

## [Updated Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/5VPGR/7/)

Comment: remove the alert it is ignoring the focus field

Comment: Hey thanks, @Manwal it's working. I'll get back to you in a few minutes to discuss why my original code didn't work.

Comment: @manwal and it was an error picking text of MetaTitleTxt and putting at same text box as I typed it wrong. I had to type out the code manually from my IDE to here since the development environment is on another offline PC. I have edited it now.

Comment: @manwal can you explain to me why my code didn't work as expected?

Comment: @Rijumone you was binding **keyup** event after checking condition but you have to check every time when **Keyup** event occur. and don't forget to delete you comment after i read them.

Comment: @Manwal Thanks for the explaination. And it's okay about the comment. Marking this as correct answer.

Answer (score 0):

I have edited a bit to make it work as you wanted , Correct me if it is wrong :

```
metaTitleHasBeenEdited = 0;
$('#MetaTitleTxt').on('keyup', function () {
    //Use this if you want to reset the flag incase if the both text field is equal i n case of manual edit
    if ($('#MetaTitleTxt').val() == $("#PageHeadingTxt").val()) {
        metaTitleHasBeenEdited = 0;
        return true;
    }
    metaTitleHasBeenEdited++;
});

$('#PageHeadingTxt').on('keyup', function () {
    alert(metaTitleHasBeenEdited);
    if (metaTitleHasBeenEdited <= 0) {
        $('#MetaTitleTxt').val($("#PageHeadingTxt").val());
    }
});
```

And here is the [Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/C549S/1/)

Comment: thanks @pawal, this one is also good.
However, can you explain to me why my code didn't work as expected?

Comment: glad it help you out. !!